# How to make my Angular frontend communicate with PHP backend?

Tags: php, angular

I created an Angular frontend and now I want it to communicate with my PHP backend. When running ng serve I get a Warning: WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js 167:24-52
"export '**platform_browser_private**' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'. Chrome shows the same warning and an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined
How can I solve this?

App.component.html:

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

App.component.ts:

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ServerService } from './server.service';

/**
 * @title Filter autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  megyek: string[];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serverService.getMegyek()
    .subscribe(
      (megyek: any[]) => this.megyek = megyek,
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.megyek.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ServerService } from './server.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
} from '@angular/material';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Server } from 'selenium-webdriver/safari';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  imports: []
})
export class MaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [ServerService],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  schemas: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Server.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  storeServers(servers: any[]) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    // return this.http.post('https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data.json',
    //   servers,
    //   {headers: headers});
    return this.http.put('https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data.json',
      servers,
      {headers: headers});
  }
  getMegyek() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/Varosok/Controller/Controller/ControllerCity.php?content=megyek')
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          const data = response.json();
          /*for (const server of data) {
            server.name = 'FETCHED_' + server.name;
          }*/
          return data;
        }
      )
      .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
          return Observable.throw('Something went wrong');
        }
      );
  }
  getAppName() {
    return this.http.get('https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/appName.json')
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          return response.json();
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend first to upgrade to the latest angular v7. https://update.angular.io/
This line "import { Server } from 'selenium-webdriver/safari';" can also be deleted as it is related to selenium.